# Wildfly Java Application: Vulnerability to host header attacks on certain URLs

Tags: java, http-headers, wildfly, servlet-filters, web.xml

I have a Java application running on Wildfly. It was found that the application seems to be vulnerable to host header attacks on certain URLs. The application has several filters that should handle this but certain requests are not going through them and are then vulnerable. It seems that when certain urls don't end with a `/`, this can happen.

My web.xml file is set up like this:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>root_path</param-name>
    <param-value>app/</param-value>
</context-param>

...

<filter>
    <filter-name>AppFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.foo.bar.AppFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AppFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here's an example curl request showing the host header issue:

```bash
curl -v 'localhost:80/app' -H 'Host: example.org:123'
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /app HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.org:123
> User-Agent: curl/7.87.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://example.org:123/app/
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Fri, 05 May 2023 23:18:08 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

If I add a `/` to the end of the URL like this: `localhost:80/app/`, the vulnerability is no longer present and the request goes through the application's filters as expected.

I've tried modifying the web.xml a bit with no success. I changed the `root_path` to just `app` instead of `app/` and added `/` and `*` `url-patterns` to the `filter-mapping` but none of these worked.

I'm wondering if there's some config in the web.xml I'm missing or if there's something I can do in the standlone.xml to address this.

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using?

Comment: 15.0.1. Old, but not able to upgrade currently

Comment: This is probably the best answer https://developer.jboss.org/message/978745#978745